# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'members.urls'

Tags: python, django, authentication, module

I tried to start a app so that I can create a Login for my blog but I came by this error.
So I thought to post a question in stack over flow.  I hope yu can take some time to answer my question.

This is the trace back error,

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Selvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Selvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\simpleblog\virt\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\simpleblog\virt\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\simpleblog\virt\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\simpleblog\virt\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\simpleblog\virt\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\simpleblog\virt\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\simpleblog\virt\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\simpleblog\virt\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\simpleblog\virt\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\simpleblog\virt\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\simpleblog\virt\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Selvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\simpleblog\ablog\ablog\urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    path('members/', include('members.urls')),
  File "C:\simpleblog\virt\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Selvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'members.urls'
```

Here is the url for members

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserRegisterView

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserRegisterView.as_view()name='register'),
```

]

Here is the urls for ablog

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('myblog.urls')),
    path('members/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('members/', include('members.urls')),

]
```

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
```

How do I solve this error.

Comment: `url.py` or `urls.py`? Note that you need to add a comma to `path('register/', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),`

Comment: its urls.py sorry for the spelling mistake

Comment: How do I solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

At first Correct your urlpatterns:(you forgot , )

`path('register/', UserRegisterView.as_view(),name='register'),`

also make sure for migrations

Comment: No, because I created the urls.py in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and I was missing the urls.py file in my app.
Add urls.py file in members app.